# IEnumerable list through override chain

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

Alright, hard to phrase an exact title for this question, but here goes... I have an abstract class called Block, that looks something like this:

```
public abstract class Block
{
   public bool Enabled{get; private set;}

   public virtual IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetDefaultUsages()
   {
      yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Enabled", "true");
   }
}
```

And say I have a subclass:

```
public class Form : Block
{
   public string Key{get; private set;}

   public override IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetDefaultUsages()
   {
       yield return new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Key", string.Empty);

       // can't do: yield return base.GetDefaultUsages()
   }
}
```

The idea is that GetDefaultUsages() will always return an IEnumerable containing all the string,string pairs that were specififed through the entire inheritance chain. I was initially hoping that the yield keyword would support a statement like:

```
yield return (some IEnumerable<T> object);
```

But apparently that doesn't work. I realize that I could do:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in base.GetDefaultUsages())
{
   yield return kv;
}
```

But I was hoping for a slightly cleaner syntax (and avoiding creating all the unnecessary intermediate IEnumerators).

Anyone got any ideas of a good way to implement this???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested yield return with IEnumerable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270024/nested-yield-return-with-ienumerable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to do something like the foreach method because the `base.GetDefaultUsages()` return an IEnumerable. `yield return` deals with single items, not collections. Although it would be nice if `yield return` could return a collection of object.

2 weeks ago John Oxley asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270024/nested-yield-return-with-ienumerable).

**Edit:**
It seems that Bart Jacobs, Eric Meyer, Frank Piessens and Wolfram Schulte already wrote [a very interesting paper](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/cache/papers/cs2/355/http:zSzzSzwww.cs.kuleuven.ac.bezSz~frankzSzPAPERSzSzFTfJP2005.pdf/iterators-revisited-proof-rules.pdf) about something they call nested iterators, which is basically what you're asking for.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I said in the question?

Comment: Yup, yield foreach isn't there yet.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/wesdyer/archive/2007/03/23/all-about-iterators.aspx for some discussion

Comment: Yeah and my answer is confirming your solution to the problem. A foreach enumerating the base collection is the solution thus far. Hopefully in the future C# will support returning collections with yield return.

Comment: Alrightey, thanks for the link to the John Oxley question anyways, some good material there