# Simple way to yield an array in parallel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

Newer version of C# has `async`/`await`. But in Unity there is only `yield`. **How do I implement a method where I can `yield` in parallel?**

Similar to `Promise.all([])` in Javascript, we don't care which one finishes first, we only care when they are all done.

To give more context, imagine you are designing a procedural terrain generator that generate *in chunks*; and you have already setup each chunk to generate using a `ThreadPool`, and then provide an API that returns an `IEnumerator`:

```
IEnumerator GenerateChunk() {
  // procedural generation
  // queue itself onto a ThreadPool
  // when done, yield
}

IEnumerator GenerateChunks() {
  for (int i = 0; i < chunks.Length; i++) {
    yield return chunks[i].GenerateChunk();
  }
}

void GenerateMap() {
  StartCoroutine(GenerateChunks());
}
```

Can we do something like `yield IEnumerator[]`?

**UPDATE**: I am not sure I have expressed myself clearly. Basically I want to kick start all `GenerateChunk` at once, and allow them to finish as fast as possible, instead of yielding one after another.

Is my code already doing that, or do I need anything else?

Comment: The correct answer might be `Enumerable.Concat()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270024/nested-yield-return-with-ienumerable

Comment: **TL;DR: Ignore all above, my question is [better summarized here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/difference-between-yield-return-ienumerator-and-yield-return-startcoroutine.432571/). I apologize for not making this clear at the get-go.**

Answer (score 1):

```
yield return StartCoroutine(chunks[i].GenerateChunk());
```

Comment: This will still yield sequentially, I have tested it to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I read your question, read the answers and the comments you left and I believe that you do **not** understand how coroutine work.

Coroutine does not run in parallel. It will run your code in order and at-same time, in the same `Thread`.

> **UPDATE**: I am not sure I have expressed myself clearly. Basically I want to kick start all GenerateChunk at once, and allow them to finish
>   as fast as possible, instead of yielding one after another.
>
> Is my code already doing that, or do I need anything else?

**No**. If you want to call that function as fast as position, you should not `yield` after each function. Each time you `yield`, you are waiting for one frame. Did I even mention that you are not even calling the `GenerateChunk` function properly? Look closely, you will notice that too. `GenerateChunk` function is a coroutine function and must be be called with `StartCoroutine()`.

Do **not** yield after starting `GenerateChunk` in the for loop. You should only yield or break outside the for loop function. You can run a simple performance test between your code and the code below to verify this with [Stopwatch](https://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch).

```
IEnumerator GenerateChunk()
{
    // procedural generation
    // queue itself onto a ThreadPool
    // when done, yield
}

IEnumerator GenerateChunks()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < chunks.Length; i++)
    {
        StartCoroutine(GenerateChunk());
    }
    yield break;
    //Or yield return null;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I do know they run in the same thread, and I do know how yield chain works. By parallel I mean `resolve` in non-deterministic order.

Comment: Also `GenerateChunk` returns an `IEnumerator`, I can yield it, it will eventually bubble up to the main `StartCoroutine` in `GenerateMap`. I don't think you need to wrap it again.

Comment: While I am no expert in Unity coroutine, I think if you don't `yield return StartCoroutine()`, it will execute on its own, ie. even when `GenerateChunks` finishes, some of the `GenerateChunk()` might still be running.

Comment: I read your last two comments several times and don't still understand what you are trying to say.....

Comment: see http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/difference-between-yield-return-ienumerator-and-yield-return-startcoroutine.432571/