# How to call an IEnumerable method from an IEnumerable method?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I have a code which is similar to the following, but more complex:

```
IEnumerable<SomeObject> GetObjects()
{
   if (m_SomeObjectCollection == null)
   {
      yield break;
   }

   foreach(SomeObject object in m_SomeObjectCollection)
   {
      yield return object;
   }

   GetOtherObjects();
}

IEnumerable<SomeObject> GetOtherObjects()
{
...
}
```

I have just realized, that `GetOtherObjects()` method *cannot be called* from `OtherObjects()` method. There are *no errors*, but the *iteration stops*. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Do a `foreach` over `GetOtherObjects()` just like you did with `m_SomeObjectCollection`.

Comment: As written, your method wouldn't need an iterator in the first place: `return m_SomeObjectCollection ?? GetOtherObjects() ?? Enumerable.Empty<SomeObject>()` or some variation thereof should do. (Although, if you can, try to get rid of having `null` in the first place -- having collections always be instantiated, even if empty, is useful to have as an invariant.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested yield return with IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270024/nested-yield-return-with-ienumerable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `foreach` and `yield return`:

```
IEnumerable<SomeObject> GetObjects()
{
   if (m_SomeObjectCollection == null)
   {
      yield break;
   }

   foreach(SomeObject item in m_SomeObjectCollection)
   {
      yield return item;
   }

   foreach (var item in GetOtherObjects())
     yield return item;
}
```

Another possibility is *Linq* `Concat`:

```
Enumerable<SomeObject> GetObjects()
{
   return m_SomeObjectCollection == null
     ? new SomeObject[0] // yield break emulation: we return an empty collection
     : m_SomeObjectCollection.Concat(GetOtherObjects());  
}
```